# Laravel relation "with" количество связанных записей

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relation

Всем привет. Конструкция такого вида:

```
Category::with('articles')->get();
```

вернет мне список категорий и вложенный массив связанных статей...
Каким образом можно ограничить количество возвращаемых связанных записей? То есть список категорий + вложенный массив последних n связанных статей?

Пробовал конструкцию:

```
Category::with(['articles' => function ($query) {
            $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
            $query->limit(3);
        }])->get();
```

Возвращает список категорий, но в relations какой-то разнобой, где-то 3 записи, где-то вообще пустой массив

Answer (score 0):

```
->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(3);
```

Это можно в связь добавить если что) или просто сортировку, а лимит уже в калбэке

а пустой массив видимо потому, что записей нет